# onLayout error after updating Android studio and SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

Yesterday I updated Android Studio to 2.1.3 and and also installed Android 7.0 Nougat (API 24) using SDK Manager. After that I Created a new project choosing `Navigation Drawer Activity` and I see this error in `activity_main.xml`,

```
Rendering Problems:
onLayout error
```

here is the error details:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable_Delegate.nCreateTreeFromCopy(JJ)J
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.nCreateTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.access$400(VectorDrawable.java:204)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.createNativeTreeFromCopy(VectorDrawable.java:837)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable$VectorDrawableState.<init>(VectorDrawable.java:812)
at android.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawable.mutate(VectorDrawable.java:268)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.setIcon(NavigationMenuItemView.java:208)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.initialize(NavigationMenuItemView.java:113)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:415)
at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onBindViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:338)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5825)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5858)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5094)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4970)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2029)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1414)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1377)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:578)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3315)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3124)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout_Original(RecyclerView.java:3568)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout_Original(DrawerLayout.java:1221)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout_Original(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:433)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17520)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:338)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:429)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:350)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:520)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$2.compute(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:967)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:508)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.access$600(RenderTask.java:75)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:620)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask$3.call(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.runRenderAction(RenderService.java:371)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:617)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.render(RenderTask.java:639)
at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:519)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is the picture:

[image]

How can I solve this error?

**Update:** This error disappears when I pick lower API versions such as 23 for rendering, But it still exist for API 24.

Comment: watch out change https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: and what will I find there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out updating The support Library to `24.2.1` solves the problem.